# What makes .svn/pristine grow?

Tags: svn

I have a subversion working copy on an embedded linux system with (very) limited disk size.

svn version is 1.9.3

When I do the check-out, .svn/pristine directory takes 14MB

After "some time & some work", it has grown up to 78MB.

If I run "svn cleanup", it goes down only to 71MB

If I erase .svn and re-do the checkout, it is 14MB again.

My question are

- What makes it grows that much (x5!) if only 14MB are needed ?
- What could i do to reduce its size back to 14MB without requiring a "rm" + "svn co" ?

Comment: I've replaced your term "client repository" (which doesn't exist in Subversion and makes it all confusing) with "working copy" because I understood that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For Tortoise SVN the option or parameter is /vacuum.

SVN 1.8 introduced automatic vacuuming of pristines to the cleanup command and 1.9 made it and other features optional

Reference [SVN: Vacuum/delete pristine copies from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1059504/svn-vacuum-delete-pristine-copies-from-command-line)

Comment: In SVN 1.9, there is no option "--vacuum". It actually arrived in subversion 1.10.

Comment: Please check the documentation from here https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html

Comment: @D A TortoiseSVN doesn't help for embedded linux